# C another Memory / Seg fault error

Tags: c, linux, memory

[EDIT:]
I have removed a lot of code now.  And I have reduced it to a more straight forward question.

Is it OK, to pass this variable...

```
char Record_Info[file_length + 1];
```

to another function, like this:

```
listdir(tempdesc, 0, sockid, Record_Info);
```

which uses this header:

```
int listdir(char *dirname, int lvl, int sockid, char Record_Info[])
```

And the listdir() can call its-self many times?

.

*** Orig Question ***

I was wondering if another set of eyes can look at this please.  It was working, but I added some more code (probably more `sprintf`, near the bottom) and now a `Segmentation fault` occurs.

This program creates/sends the web page, correctly, but crashes when it returns from the `send_recordings_list()` function back to the `parsing_request()` function.  I don't think its necessary to understand how its formatting the data from the file, but I included that bit anyway.

For the most part, I'm using static variables, and when I attempt to `free()` any thing, it causes another seg fault, or gcc lib fault.  Also I am unsure if passing the variables between the functions() might be causing the issue?

Also worth mentioning, a different function (not shown in here) sends out a web page which is about 4MB, I can call this one many times and it does not crash. I have placed a few `// ******` at some lines which might be of interest?

Oh yes, I have not done much standard error handling yet... (I'll do it later), so assume its a spherical chicken in a vacuum.

.

So it starts at `parsing_request()`

goes to `send_recordings_list()`

goes to `listdir()` . (this calls its self many times)

back to `send_recordings_list()`

. (seg fault here)

back to `parsing_request()`

.

I'm hoping some will go 'ahh i see what you did `fool`......'

Embedded Linux 2.6.27, GCC 4.2.4, 32MB Ram

```
void parsing_request(int sockid, char *buff)
{
  char *res_line=malloc(MAXLINE), path[MAXLINE], *line;
  // Cut code
  if (strcmp(line, "/recordings_body.htm") == 0)
  {
    send_recordings_list (sockid);      // ****** IT GOES HERE 1st ******
    return;
  }
  free (res_line);
  return;
}




int send_recordings_list(int sockid)
{
    int  hnd;
    int  hnd2;
    char tempdesc[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];


    // Copy all of the data <1 MiB   (Slow reading)
    int file_length = lseek (hnd2, 0, SEEK_END);
    char Record_Info[file_length + 1];      // ******
    lseek (hnd2, 0, SEEK_SET);
    read (hnd2, Record_Info, file_length);
    close (hnd2);

    // Cut out code

    del_file_cnt = 0;
    sprintf (tempdesc, "%s/Recordings", TOPPY_DIR);
    listdir(tempdesc, 0, sockid, Record_Info);        // ***** Major 2nd call here
    return 0;
}





int listdir(char *dirname, int lvl, int sockid, char Record_Info[])
{

    int i;
    DIR* d_fh;
    struct dirent* entry;
    char longest_name[4096];
    char tempdesc[4096], morespace[128];
    int  row_col;
    char chan_name[128], alt_name[128], desc[500], category[128], rec_time[14], start_time[14], end_time[14];
    char trim_file_name[128], trim_file_name2[128], trim_alt_name[128], file_links[1535];
    char logo[128];
    int  length, u_score, dot;
    char *looky_pos1, *looky_pos2;
    int  is_match;

    struct tm tm_rec, tm_start, tm_end;
    time_t tim_rec, tim_start, tim_end;

    // Cut out code

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as `C++` ? It looks like plain C to me (and very archaic C at that).

Comment: oops, I've changed c++ to c, sorry

Comment: Far too much code in the question. Trim it down to the specific bits you think are involved.

Comment: "I'll add error handling later" has _never_ worked. Error handling _must_ be part of the overall architecture.

Comment: @auselen, so it won't crash but silently do unspeakable things with truncated strings. I prefer crashes any day.

Comment: Wellcome to SO. This is not a site for code review but for concrete technical questions. Please nail your problem down until you are able to ask a well structured question. Voting to close.

Comment: For network code : **use the returnvalue from read(),write() send() recv()** , and do not trust on buffers being NUL-terminated. 2) the `string[strlen(string) -4]` is very suspect. So is the excessive use of strcat().

Comment: @vonbrand what about if he was handling a nuke :) that one was just a recommendation. I thought no one was using sprintf's anymore.

Comment: hello, I'll look into what people have just said...

Comment: @auselen, if this code was for handling a nuke, the more the reason to prefer it crashing in testing instead of flying to the wrong end of the world when used in anger.

Comment: @auselen, sprintf is alive and well. Part of the standard, even. Yes, you have to use it with care. Remember what was written in big red letters on the C box? "Careful! Very sharp objects inside. Not to be handled by children."

Comment: Answer to second question: yes, it is correct. But I would suggest to add a fifth parameter to the `listdir()` function to indicate the amount of space in the buffer. If listdir() is recursive, you *might* have some problems.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, this is a hopeless mess. Learn how to use Linux tools like valgrind and gdb. Check carefully that the memory you request is eventually freed *once* and after its use is done. Check that you don't pass pointers to local variables out of functions. Check that your strings are long enough to accomodate the data expected (or check as part as your as of now nonexistent error handling).

One debugging strategy that is suprisingly effective is the Teddy Bear Consultant: Get a teddy bear and explain your problem to it step by step. Only if that doesn't help is a real human warranted. [It works because sorting out your understanding to explain it forces you to really think it through.]

Comment: "Check that you don't pass pointers to local variables out of functions", hmmm OK I better check this, thanks.  unfortunately valgrind don't work on this little box, but I'll look into gdb.   Teddy Bear :)

Comment: @Matt, try debugging your program on a more substantial box. Debugging is painful enough to provide the best environment possible...

Answer (score 1):

After looking quickly at your code, you have two options:

1. Learn how to handle errors, how to manage resources and how to avoid global variables
2. Use a programming language which does it for you

Both will take a long time but using the second approach, you will be much more productive.

I suggest to try to implement the above with Python just to get a feeling.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your most recent post, asking if you can pass the character value into the function... I don't understand what you're trying to do. In the function prototype you have the final parameter as a char variable_name[], are you trying to pass a array in? If so, why not use a pointer?

so the prototype would like like:

```
int listdir(char *dirname, int lvl, int sockid, char* Record_Info);
```

Passing by reference always tends to give you a little bit more control, whether you want it or not. Are you trying to pass in a specific element of an array?

Comment: thanks, anyway. But I spotted the issue.  basically a typo